# Using the energy consumption profiler in Visual Studio 2015 Community Update 3

Tags: performance, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, windows-store-apps, uwp

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community version, and I tried to use the energy consumption tool.

I used am trying to use : Debug -> Profiler -> Start Diagnostic Tools Without Debugging...

However, I found that the "Energy Consumption" option is not available. (The option was shown but was shown as "not available." and is greyed out)

Is the energy consumption profiler not available for the community edition I am using? Or is there a setting I missed..?

I am making a UWP store application and have tried to do it while set to debug/release and also phone and tablet.

Comment: Thank you for informing us this issue. I made a demo and reproduced the problem. I've reported a Bug [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3107446). Let's wait for response.

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT did you get any response for this bug? the link seems to be broken by now (perhaps private?)

Answer (score 3):

We have deprecated the Energy Consumption profiler in VS 2015 and beyond. We found that it wasn’t broadly used and the information it provided wasn’t more of an rough approximation, which had limited usability for most developers.

/Kenneth Auchenberg,
Program Manager, Microsoft.

Comment: You guys made such a huge deal about it... And now it has been removed? How are we supposed to power optimize our applications for windows tablets and phones?

Comment: Is this for real? How come MSDN articles about that topic don't mention this change at all?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem deprecated atleast from the documentation link below 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn263062.aspx. It seems to be applicable to VS 2015

It could be that documentation hasn't caught up with reality ...(I am also seeing it grey out)

Any alternative techniques to measure/estimate the energy consumption of UWP applications.

Thanks,